# How do I see that the package "python-magic" should be imported as "magic"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Suppose I install the package `python-magic` using `pip3 install python-magic`.

If I search for the package in `site-packages`, I can see from the `top_level.txt` that `python-magic` should be imported as `magic`. However, that file seems not to be standard:

```
nlykkei:~$ ls /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ | grep magic
magic.py
python_magic-0.4.18.dist-info/
nlykkei:~$ cat /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/python_magic-0.4.18.dist-info/top_level.txt
magic
```

How could I infer that it should be imported as `>>> import magic` using `pip3`?

Comment: Have you tested:
>>> import magic

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/

Comment: @Hackerman, OP asking about how the package importing name could be different from the installation name.

Comment: Just a side-note. It is a feature that the names can differ: _"Python and PyPI support multiple distributions providing different implementations of the same package. For instance the unmaintained-but-seminal PIL distribution provides the PIL package, and so does Pillow, an actively-maintained fork of PIL!"_ (from Python packaging docs)

Comment: @Hanz No. OP is **explicitly** asking *How can I easily infer that it should be imported as `import magic`*. How to **know** that it is imported with a different name, not how is it possible...

Answer (score 0):

PyPi is just a host of a bunch of Packages and Modules for Python, the installation command (for pip) can be different.

the package (python-magic) export the magic.py file to the /site-packages/ directory which can be imported anywhere your python script executed.

How did this works?
Well, by doing `import magic` you are including all of the /site-packages/magic.py file content. The `import` statement can import any Python file, just type `import <file>` so you can use the file content by simply typing `<file>.foo()`, etc. (dont include the .py extension)

Example:
(myfile.py)

```py
def introduction():
    print("This is myfile.py introduction")
```

(yourscript.py)

```py
import myfile

myfile.introduction()
# Output:
# This is myfile.py introduction
```

Note that these files are in the same directory

Comment: This is all nice and well, but the question is how are you supposed to know when installing a package called `python-magic` that it is imported as `magic`. Lets say you ship this example and call the packege `python-hanz`. How do the users supposed to know that it is imported as `myfile`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo, documentation does explain about that.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, so in general there is no clue except documentation about how a package should be imported? There is no command like `pip3 show magic-python` to see usage information about a package.